# openssl 1.0.2k s_server doesn't work with ecdsa certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

My openssl verison:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

Openssl 1.0.2 cipher suits, **`openssl ciphers "aECDH" -v |column -t`**:

```
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384      TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH  Enc=AES(256)     Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA           SSLv3    Kx=ECDH/RSA    Au=ECDH  Enc=AES(256)     Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA         SSLv3    Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH  Enc=AES(256)     Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-NULL-SHA           SSLv3    Kx=ECDH/ECDSA  Au=ECDH  Enc=None         Mac=SHA1
...
```

Openssl client:

```
openssl s_client -cipher "ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384" -connect localhost:8808 -curves "prime256v1"
```

Openssl server:

```
openssl s_server  -cert eccert.pem -key eckey.pem -port 8808  -curves "prime256v1"
```

When connected,Server get the error:

```
ERROR
139716706432704:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1418:
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
ACCEPT
```

The self-signed ECDSA certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: You likely want to use ECDHE not ECDH ciphers.

Comment: And if you really want to use ECDH your certificate need to have a key usage of keyAgreement. Apart from that, why do you create v1 certificates instead of v3?